# unable to troubleshoot err_too_many_redirects error

Tags: nginx, artifactory

Unable to troubleshoot the above error when accessing artifactory.inmz.net.
My nginx config is the following, am I missing something here?

```
server {

    access_log /var/log/nginx/artifactory_access.log timed_combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/artifactory_error.log;

    listen 80;
    server_name    artifactory.inmz.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://utils-1:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you `proxy_pass`ing to? If that's your entire nginx config (run `nginx -T` to be sure), it's probably the application trying to correct the URL; random guess would be making it `proxy_pass http://utils-1:8080/;`.

Comment: utils-1 is a host and a container is running on port 8080 within. Will try that thanks!